# issue with CURDATE() going back before current working month

Tags: mysql

Not sure why this query will not go back and get records before the current month. It worked fine last month, then today hits, June 1st, and it will not retrieve last months records.

Last 7 Days

```
SELECT SUM(sum) AS sum FROM cl_work_orders WHERE user_id = ? AND workorder_date <= CURDATE() AND workorder_date > (CURDATE() - 8)
```

Last 30 Days

```
SELECT SUM(sum) AS sum FROM cl_work_orders WHERE user_id = ? AND workorder_date <= CURDATE() AND workorder_date > (CURDATE() - 31)
```

Yesterday

```
SELECT SUM(sum) AS sum FROM cl_work_orders WHERE user_id = ? AND workorder_date < CURDATE() AND workorder_date > (CURDATE() - 2)
```

They all worked fine last month. Just started the site last month so was unable to see the "new month" issue prior to today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
CURDATE() - 8
```

use

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY
```

or

```
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -8 DAY)
```

The value of CURDATE() depends on the context in which you are using it - as you are trying to add a number to it, it acts as a number.  The [MySQL documentation for CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) mentions this with examples of numeric and string usage.

Comment: Awesome! That works! Thank you. I have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Interval Keyword instead.

```
SELECT SUM(sum) AS sum 
FROM cl_work_orders 
WHERE user_id = ? 
AND workorder_date < CURDATE() 
AND workorder_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Month) 

SELECT SUM(sum) AS sum 
FROM cl_work_orders 
WHERE user_id = ? 
AND workorder_date < CURDATE() 
AND workorder_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```

Give it a try. It should work for you.